# Website text is bigger in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I am making a site for a client. I have some issues in Chrome on an Android phone. I have attached an image of some normal text in a normal div that just blows up to 42px or something. The phone is a normal Samsung Galaxy S3.

There's no problems in Firefox on the same phone. And no problems at all on a desktop computer.

[image: Big text on Chrome in Android]

The CSS is like this:

```
#content.is-front .post:first-child .post-title-excerpt {
   left: 2%;
   float: left;
   z-index: 99;
   bottom: 2%;
   border: none;
   width: 92%;
   padding: 2%;
   overflow: hidden; /* not on the online site. Would prevent text from going out of box, but would not change the big font. */
   color: #ffffff;
   max-height: 133px;
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 14px !important;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

And the HTML would be similar to this:

```
<div id="post-138" class="post-138 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-torsten tag-featured">
    <div class="post-header">
       <a href="http://copenhero.dk/torsdagsbar-guide/">
       <img width="940" height="390" src="http://copenhero.dk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Torsdagsbar-forside-featured2.jpg" class="attachment-front-featured-thumb wp-post-image" alt="Torsdagsbar forside featured2">              </a>
<div class="post-title-excerpt">
    <div class="post-category"><a href="http://copenhero.dk/kategori/torsten/">Tørsten</a></div>
    <div class="post-title"><a href="http://copenhero.dk/torsdagsbar-guide/">Guide: Torsdagsbarer i København</a></div>
    <div class="post-excerpt"><p>Øl, drinks og shots har som bekendt ikke kun den ønskede effekt i weekenden. Torsdag kan være en perfekt gå-ud dag med gode tilbud, flere siddepladser og knapt så meget pres på fadølshanerne rundt omkring i København. Copenhero har været på field-research, og er gået videnskabeligt og alkoholisk til værks for at finde lidt for […]</p>
</div>
<a class="post-permalink" href="http://copenhero.dk/torsdagsbar-guide/">Læs mere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some rule for .post-excerpt p later on in the css that might affect the text? Have you tried giving the problematic tag its own id and set specific css to make it go away?

Comment: @DavidSvensson According to Firebug there is not rules for the font-size to change. And it works in Firefox, that's why I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: I've tried to change the font-size to em instead of px, but it's still the same. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the Android browser does automatic resizing for non reponsive content.
Just use em instead of pixels. Remember: usually 1em = 16px

```
#content.is-front .post:first-child .post-title-excerpt {
    ...
    font-size: 0.85em !important;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you cleaned the cache? Is it Chrome or the default browser?

Comment: It's working now. My client did not clear his cache before testing. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your CSS on your body

> -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

http://css-tricks.com/prevent-iphone-text-enlargement/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font-size in em instead of px. Using px values never worked me with mobile devices. Also try to separate your nastier rules with media queries. Though for debugging setting an id for the problematic tag helps you debugging.